# Php and javascript array - skipping blank values and adding to new array?

Tags: php, javascript, regex, arrays, search

I have an array in php that contains all the lines of a text files (each line being one value of the array). My text file had blank lines so the array has blank lines too. I wanted to search the array for a certain value like this:

```
$array = array();

        $lines = file("textfile.txt"); //file in to an array
        foreach ($lines as $line)
        {
            if (stripos($line, "$$") !== false) 
            {
                $array[] = str_replace("$$", "", $line);

            }
        }
```

The code above is searching for a $$ and replacing it with a blank. The text file holds a line with a $$1 or any number and I want it to find all instances of that line, which it is doing.

My problem is that I want it to find the next 5 lines that aren't blank after finding the $$(number) and put them into a multi dimensional array. The multidimensional array looking similar to this (the program is a test in case you are wondering why the array is named the way it is):

```
$test = array(
    array('question' => 'What is the answer', 'ansa' => "answera", 'ansb' => "answerb", 'ansc' => "answerc", 'ansd' => "answerd"), // $test[1]
    array('question' => 'What is the answer', 'ansa' => "answera", 'ansb' => "answerb", 'ansc' => "answerc", 'ansd' => "answerd"), // $test[2]
);
```

The next five lines after the $$(number) are a question and four answers that need to go into the array. My code with regxp and searching isn't working so i discarded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this...

```
<?php

$lines = array_filter(file('text.txt')); //file in to an array
$questions = array();

// find your starts and pull out questions
foreach ($lines as $k=>$line)
{
    if (stripos($line, "$$") !== false) 
    {
        $questions[] =  array_slice($lines, $k, 5);
    }
}


// dump
var_dump($questions);
```

See [php manual for array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: This wouldn't check for empty lines, which can be added simply. Also, you may want to replace it with a `for` loop so you can skip over the next file lines so it doesn't loop through them unnecessarily.

Comment: drop empty lines with `$lines = array_filter(file('text.txt'));`... Hosh, you are right, however this is just example.

Comment: Yes, the most important line I was confused about. Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried the code to remove the empty lines and it didn't work.

Comment: hm... if lines contain spaced they are not empty. try this `$lines = array_filter(array_map('trim', $lines))`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `preg_replace_callback`?

Something along these lines should work:

```
<?php

function replace_callback($matches) {
    var_dump($matches);
}

preg_replace_callback('/\$\$[0-9]+\s+([^'.PHP_EOL.']+){5}/is', 'replace_callback', file_get_contents('textfile.txt'));

?>
```